# Concerning a property of Gaussian Primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Consider the ring of Gaussian integerse $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Let $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ be a prime.

Why does the identity

$$N(\pi) = \pi \bar{\pi} = p_1\cdot \ldots \cdot p_k$$

, where $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are rational primes, imply that $\pi \mid p_i$ for some $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$?

I suppose that this is a direct consequence of the supposed primality of $\pi$ (i.e. if $\pi = \alpha\beta$, then $\pi \mid \alpha$ or $\pi \mid \beta$), but I do not quite understand it. Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: Well, as you said, the identity implies $\pi \mid p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k$. By applying the primality property inductively, you get that $\pi \mid p_i$ for some $i$. What exactly is the part that's not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primality of $\pi$ means that if $\pi \mid \alpha \beta$, then $\pi \mid \alpha$ or $\pi \mid \beta$. (What you wrote is the definition of an irreducible element, which is a weaker property.) Using this property, you can show by induction that
$\pi \mid \alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_k$ implies $\pi \mid \alpha_j$ for some $j$.